# How to get TaskManager containers registered with Job Manager container for flink?

Tags: docker, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Trying to play with flink docker image for the first time. I am following instructions at https://hub.docker.com/_/flink which says

> You can run a JobManager (master).
>
> `$ docker run --name flink_jobmanager -d -t flink jobmanager`
>
> You can also run a TaskManager (worker). Notice that workers need to register
>   with the JobManager directly or via ZooKeeper so the master starts to
>   send them tasks to execute.
>
> `$ docker run --name flink_taskmanager -d -t flink taskmanager`

Can someone explain how does this taskmanager register with the jobmanager from these commands?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to start a Flink cluster on Docker I would strongly recommend to use docker-compose whose config file you can also find [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/flink).

If you want to set up a Flink cluster using docker manually, then you have to start the containers so that they can resolve their names. First you need to create a custom network via

```
docker network create my-network
```

Next, you have to start the `jobmanager` with this network and configure the name as well as the hostname to be same. That way Flink will bind to the hostname which is resolvable.

```
docker run --name jobmanager --hostname jobmanager --rm --net my-network -d -t flink jobmanager
```

Last but not least, we need to start the `taskmanager` and tell him the name of the JobManager. This is done by setting the environment variable `JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS` to `jobmanager.

```
docker run --name taskmanager --net my-network -e JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager -t -d flink taskmanager
```

Comment: Thank you, Till. It works. The documentation could be better written like how you explained.

Comment: Happy to have helped you. If this answer is correct, then please accept it so that others see that it is a valid solution.